# How to create Multimoduling Spring Boot Maven project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I did:

- created project with some dependencies.
- created first maven module(web).
- created second maven module(model).
- moved code to web module: main class + controller.
- deleted src from root(because it is already empty)
- in model module created entity, added dependencies JPA/MySQl driver to pom.xml of this module.
- in web module added dependency of model module.

Project runs without errors, **web** module sees **model** dependency. But code of entity doesnt work(not creating table in database). If i move class to **web** module - it works. Exactly - it works, but dependencies of JPA/MySQL are still in **model** module.

What i am doing wrong?

I tried to change names of groupId and artifactId, with package`s names of modules, moved application.propeties to **model** module - does not help.

My project:

-**model**/src/main/java and resources/com/example/demo/model

pom.xml:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example.demo.model</groupId>
    <artifactId>model</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>module-model</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

-**web**/src/main/java and resources/com/example/demo/web

application.properties with database connection to MySQL.

pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example.demo.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>module-web</name>
    <description>Web project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.demo.model</groupId>
            <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Main pom.xml:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <name>demo</name>

    <modules>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>model</module>
    </modules>
```

Comment: Try with adding @EntityScan(basePackageClasses = EntityPackage.class) annotation to config class. "EntityPackage.class" can be interface in the root of entity package.

Comment: interface of what? Or you mean just empty interface just to for this annotation?

Comment: Yes just empty interface or you can use path to entity package @EntityScan("com.example.entity").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anrew you also may adjust @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.example.demo.model", "com.example.demo.web" }) annotation with "scanBasePackages" it uses @ComponentScan. And bear in mind that you have to add this annotation in "Web project"

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.demo.model","com.example.demo.web" })
public class WebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: A little confused with this answers( I added this scanBasePackages = not works. I added @ComponentScan (Redundant declaration: SpringBootApplication already applies given ComponentScan), tried to add to ComponentScan that packages = didnt help. Could you write exactly how my main class should looks?
From your example my code has no error, but database still empty.

Comment: and I dont understand this: " And bear in mind that you have to add this annotation in "Web project"". Because where can I add it anymore? I have psvm method in "Web project", so nowhere more I can add it of course. Or not?

Answer (score 0):

@ComponentScan tells Spring in which packages you have annotated classes which should be managed by Spring. and by default, it scans the main package so if spring boot application under com. example only all Classes under this package will be scanned.
so if you moved them under different package Spring application will not recognize them.

if this is the case you can add multiple packages to be scanned
@ComponentScan({ "x.y.z", "x.y.z.dao" })

Comment: Doesnt help to me